# SwiftUI App freezes for a few seconds before coming to foreground

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI app that has a lot of animation components to it. When the app is in foreground, the Custom Animation on Shapes work fine, no latency. They run smoothly at 60 FPS.

When the app comes to foreground after going from background, the app freezes for a few seconds and becomes completely non-responsive. Then it comes back to normal behavior.

I tried running the Time profiler instrument but the main thread is not blocked. Seems like there is no work happening on the CPU. What is interesting is that there is a gap between the background state and the foreground state (In the app lifecycle track) of the app as shown in the image.

What might be causing the app to freeze? Any ideas on how to debug this issue?

If it helps, the app also has a core-motion component to it which I am not pausing when the app goes to background.

[image]

Comment: Well, without knowing the code, and seeing these CPU loads, it might very well be your code causing the issue. Remember that animations are all on the main thread, they are played sequentially one after another. When something goes to the background a "Snapshot" is taken, barring any background operations. Meaning your animations and their current locations,data, etc. are all frozen. When the view comes back they are un-frozen. If you have a ton of them then it can cause lag. Perhaps use a method to clear animations when the view goes to background, and restart animations again from start.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention was that this happens once when I try to bring the app to the foreground like 5 or 6 times, other times it works fine. When I am running in debug mode with the phone plugged in, then the app freezes and then resumes, but when I am not running the app from XCode, it freezes and then crashes.

Comment: Do you have the ability to test on a device? To rule-out xCode being XCode.

Comment: I am testing on device. Just running the Instruments. I think I found what was causing the bug but I am still not sure how exactly. I just commented out the .drawingGroup() modifier on my views and it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I considered a similar issue. In my case it turned out that the modifier .drawingGroup() caused the issue. If I start my app everything was fine, but if I put it to background and bring it to foreground again it stopped for 4 seconds. I removed the drawingGroup modifier and this issue was solved.